# HTML onload not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to use html onload event to trigger javascript, but is not working. The original code was:

html:

```
<div id='map' onload="generateMap.createMap();"></div>
```

JS:

```
var generateMap = function(){
return{
    createMap: function(){
        console.log(this.attr('id'));
        element = this.attr('id');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
    }
};
```

}

In an attempt to test, I changed the html to:

```
<div id='map' onload="alert('test');"></div>
```

Can anyone tell me why nothing is working?

Comment: what is "initialize" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the `onload` attribute is not valid for a `div` tag. You most likely intended to place the `onload` in the `body` tag.

Unfortunately, that's not the only problem.

In your `onLoad` you are referencing `generateMap` as if it is an object with method `createMap`. However, this is not the case. You have assigned `generateMap` to an anonymous function.

To get your code working, `generateMap` needs to be an object with method `createMap`.

You just need to set it as an object in the first place:

```
var generateMap = {
    createMap: function(){
        console.log(this.attr('id'));
        element = this.attr('id');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
    }
};
```

**Or** if you need to retain the anonymous function for whatever reason, you can use an immediately executing function:

```
var generateMap = (function(){
    return {
        createMap: function(){
            console.log(this.attr('id'));
            element = this.attr('id');
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm just figuring out the steps for object oriented javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** *onload* event for a div. You can use the script tag just after the div tag to emulate onload behavior.

Use this

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var generateMap = {
            createMap: function(element) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        generateMap.createMap('map');
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `generateMap.createMap('map');` needs to be in `onload` or, since the OP has indicated use of jQuery, a `$(document).ready(function(){});` function. Placing a script tag immediately after the body tag does not ensure that the JavaScript will execute after the page has loaded.

Comment: having a script tag will make sure the script gets loaded as soon as div gets loaded - that is what the solution is and the ask was. Passing the div id is all that is required in the method he is invoking.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a technique like that, but if you are intending to execute `createMap` after only the div has loaded (i.e., not the whole document), then that will work fine.

Comment: I agree with you Elliot - its not a optimal way to do it but definitely the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Chrome.. `div` tags do not have an `onload` event. Check the following two jsfiddles:

Does not work:
http://jsfiddle.net/o81e4dkr/

Works:
http://jsfiddle.net/p3osqrdn/

I do not know of a way to have an event fired when a div is loaded, unless it is being loaded in via jQuery.load(), in which case you can use the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery then I like the following function which adds onload capability to all tags:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    jQuery.each ($("[onload]"), function (index, item) {
        $(item).prop ("onload").call (item);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It has come to my attention that this will call the body onload repeatedly (ending in a horrible loop) so it's necessary to add this line to the beginning of the "each" function:

     if (new Array ("body", "iframe", "iframe", "link", "style").contains ($(item).prop ("tagName"))) return;